# Mobile site detecting

Tags: c#, php, javascript, asp.net, mobile

Whic is the best way to do next:

I have regular site, lets say: www.regular.com (example)
and mobile site: mobile.regular.com

If someone get in to the regular site via mobile (iphone, android and so on..), its enter to page who give 2 options:

1) Get in to regular-site

2) Get in to mobile-site

So far i done next:

```
<a href="http://mobile.regular.com">To Mobile site</a>

<a id="fullsite" href="http://regular.com">To regular site</a>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('fullsite').addEventListener('click',gotoFullSite,true);

    function gotoFullSite(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setCookie("viewFullSite", true, 1);
    location.href = this.getAttribute('http://regular.com');
    }
    </script>
```

What i need to put in the regular site, to auto-recognize if the user is from mobile or not? and do that in way that if someone want to display anyway the regular site, even via mobile ?

If its important:

The mobile site is in Wordpress

The regular site is at ASP.NET c#

Comment: Thanks to all Finnaly i found the answer here: [Solution](http://www.malphursinteractive.com/view-full-site-mobile-redirect-script/)

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript:

```
if(navigator.userAgent.match(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPod|BlackBerry|iPad/i)){
alert("I am mobile browser");
}else {
alert("I am desktop browser");
}
```

In C#:

```
if (Request.Headers["User-Agent"] != null && (Request.Browser["IsMobileDevice"] ==  "true" || Request.Browser["BlackBerry"] == "true"||request.UserAgent.ToLower().Contains("iphone"))
{
Response.Redirect("http://Yourwebsite.com");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Php their are libraries available to detect device/channel. For eg Mobile Detect is one such library file. Try that.

Answer (score 0):

Use `IsMobileDevice` flag.

Try with:

```
Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice
```

Redirection:

```
Response.Status="302 Moved Temporarily"
Response.AddHeader "Location","http://m.yoursite.com"
```

Hope its helpful.

Comment: Hi, thanks. lets say i done it at default.aspx of the regular site... what will happen after the user will choose "go to regular site" from mobile? it will bring him back to mobile site, no?

Answer (score 0):

You should do this on the serverside using [WURFL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/apis.php). It has versions available for native .NET integration as well as you can see on the link.

All other methods are (more) unreliable and/or not-standardized, such as the IsMobileDevice flag (also, is a laptop a mobile device or not? and with a touch screen? a hybrid laptop/tablet?)

Answer (score 0):

```
function IsMobile() {
var navi = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
if( navi.match(/android/i)
   || navi.match(/webos/i)
   || navi.match(/iphone/i)
   || navi.match(/ipad/i)
   || navi.match(/ipod/i)
   || navi.match(/blackberry/i)
   || navi.match(/windows phone/i)
 )
 {
    window.location.href = "http://mobile.regular.com";
 }    
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  IsMobile();
  //do code for regular site
});
```